# Target the ul following the active ul in a menubar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, css-selectors

I'm putting together a WP website, and on the menu bar the active menu item is underlined. All of the menu items (li) had a padding-right set on them, but I need to take it off the active element so that the border on the bottom only extends to the end of the text. To make up for it, I need to somehow target the next li but I can't quite figure out how to do it. I'm working in the context of someone else's WP theme which is always a challenge but I think this is probably doable, I just don't know quite how to combine the CSS selectors. Here's the basic menu structure:

```
<nav id="top-menu">
  <ul id="menu-top">
    <li id="menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item current-menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

To target the padding on the element, I have to use #top-menu ul > li#current-menu-item > a

So if I wanted to target the 3rd element in this example, what code would I use? Is this even possible, or am I trying to be too specific? I'm hoping some combination of child and descendant selectors, but I'm not sure how I can make it all work together. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually in situations like this I resort to a bit of jQuery.  With jQuery, you can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the li after the one you've targeted.

First, you've mixed up ids and classes.  You need to be using classes here (ids cannot be repeated):

```
<nav id="top-menu">
  <ul id="menu-top">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item current-menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a>ITEM 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then this would give you the li after the current one:

```
$('.current-menu-item').next()
```

So you could do something like add another class to it (obviously my class name is waaaayyy longer than it really needs to be!):

```
$('.current-menu-item').next().addClass('the-one-after-the-current-menu-item');
```

Which you could then style via css.

```
.the-one-after-the-current-menu-item { // styling here.... }
```

Comment: Oh yeah I was just trying to remember off the top of my head something similar to the id/class structure the theme I'm editing was using. I just wanted to give you an idea of what I was working with. I think I can probably use this solution, I don't see why it wouldn't work. I'll try it tomorrow! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "+" in CSS selects the element after whatever. In this case, something like this:

```
#current-menu-item + li {
    background: red;
}
```

Although, you may have another problem in that you can't use spaces in IDs. If the IDs in your example were classes instead, you'd be completely fine.

Comment: Oh I was just trying to remember off the top of my head something similar to the naming/identification structure the theme is using. I just wanted to put in some sort of selector whenever they have a selector, for the sake of the question. The problem I'm experiencing is that I need to target the <a> contained within the <li> tag. I know that I can target the li afterwards with the + sign. I just don't know how to combine it to target the a within it. Would #current-menu-item + li > a target the a within the following li tag?

Comment: Sure will! You can even do #current-menu-item + li a (without the >) if you want

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by russtuck91, that `current-menu-item` needs to be a class, then his answer is the one i would implement, it is the cleanest.

however if you cant change that (which you have to as you cant have spaces in id's), you can use :nth-child(x) where x is the number of child elements down:

```
#top-menu li:nth-child(3) a {
    color:red;
}
```

will still recommend russtuck91's answer though

Comment: Oh yeah it varies from page to page which one has the active class so I can't use a set number like that, unfortunately. Thanks!